# Call arbitrary methods on class like xmlrpclib.ServerProxy

Tags: python, xmlrpclib

I have a remote api accepting XMLs only that may be called like

```
api = xmlrpclib.ServerProxy(IP)
result = api.Execute({"Method": 'Method_name', "Params": [P1, P2],
                      ...  # technical values - authentication, etc
                      })
```

The technical values are not subject to change frequently - whole script would usually use same values for them, so I created a class that has a method

```
def call(self, method_name, params):
    self.api.Execute(<constructed dictionary>)
```

I was wondering if it would be possible to call these methods directly as methods of `self.api` like:

```
self.api.method_name(params)
```

Which would in turn fill in the `.Execute` and the rest for me, with the general idea like:

```
def __getattr__(self, item):
    if item in self.__dict__:
        return self.item
    else:
        return functools.partial(self.call, method_name=item)
```

So, if I defined a method in class (`self.foo`, `self.bar` and the like) - calling it would produce true results of `self.foo` and `self.bar`.

Calling it like `self.api.METHOD(params)` where `METHOD` is a custom one works, but this approach "pollutes" other methods that I didn't define, like `self.api.__repr__` and the like

Is it true that according to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14612442/how-to-handle-return-both-properties-and-functions-missing-in-a-python-class-u) my approach of overriding `__getitem__` is incorrect entirely? If so - how should I implement this?

Comment: Does `Execute` take a single dictionary or a series of keyword args? The code in the first block seems to indicate the former, but the way you invoke `partial` indicates the latter. Also, is a comprehensive list of available `Execute` methods exposed to the script?

Comment: @wilusdaman, it effectively takes a single dictionary. The way `partial` is used because there are intermittent internal and external methods that construct this dictionary and operate on its values. The comprehensive list is not available unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recently watched [a talk by Raymond Hettinger](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OSGv2VnC0go) which this post loosely reminded of, so I thought I'd link to it. I think it makes a great argument for the approach you described in you post:

**Make the API work for you**

First of all, I don't think overriding `__getattr__` is as sinful as that post might have you believe.

```
class MyAPI(object):
  base_args = {'token': 'foobarauthtoekn'}

  def __init__(self, ip):
    self._api = ServerProxy(ip)

  def _execute(self, method='', **kwargs):
    argdict = {'Method': method}
    argdict.update(MyAPI2.base_args)
    argdict.update(kwargs)
    self._api.Execute(argdict)

  def __getattr__(self, attr):
    return self.__dict__.get(
      attr, partial(self._execute, method=attr))


api = MyAPI('127.0.0.1')

# Execute({'token': ..., 'Method': 'get_users', 'arg1': 'foo' ...}) =
api.get_users(arg1='foo', arg2='bar')

# Execute({'token': ..., 'Method': 'get_data', 'foo': 'stuff' ...}) =
api.get_data(foo='stuff', bar='zxcv')
```

I like this because it's not a lot of code, and it lets us use `Execute` in a more convenient way (with keyword args), without relying on support for that from the internal API.

**Special behavior via metaclasses**

The other approach prevents us having to override `__getattr__` in case I've underestimated how much of a mistake it is, and it could also be considered more pythonic, as we explicitly enumerate the methods we'll be providing with our API wrapper:

```
class APIMeta(type):
  def __new__(cls, clsname, bases, attrs):

    def exec_generic(name):
      base_args = {'token': 'foobarauthtoekn'}
      def exec_wrapper(self, params):
        args = {'Method': name}
        args.update(base_args)
        args.update(params)
        return self._api.Execute(args)
      return exec_wrapper

    new_attrs = {
      name: val if name.startswith('__') else exec_generic(name)
      for name, val in attrs.items() }

    return super(APIMeta, cls).__new__(cls, clsname, bases, new_attrs)

class MyAPI(object, metaclass=APIMeta):
  def __init__(self, ip):
    self._api = ServerProxy(ip)

  def get_users(self):
    pass

  def get_data(self):
    pass

  # ...
```

In reality, I don't like this, since it's little more than a *very* convoluted way to write:

```
class MyAPI(object):
  _base_args = {'token': 'foobarauthtoken'}

  def __init__(self, ip):
    self._api = ServerProxy(ip)

  def get_users(self, params):
    argdict = {'Method': 'get_users'}
    argdict.update(MyAPI._base_args)
    argdict.update(params)
    return self._api.Execute(argdict)

  # ...
```

It will save you a considerable amount of typing if you have a lot of methods though, and it's also good practice in meta-programming if you're looking to get into that or deepen your understanding of the python language.

[Here's](https://repl.it/Ji58) a demo with both.

Comment: Thank you very much. This is indeed at this point purely a question of exercise, and I was very wanting to find some application for metaclasses. I will try these suggestions out and once they fit, will accept the answer if you do not mind.